# Vue chartJS/legacy- change Legend position

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-chartjs

I'm working on little project with Vue-Chart JS with Laravel backend. I used **vue2 charts**, which have import from vue-chartjs/legacy. So, what I wanted to move that Legend label into the bottom of the chart.

I tried to add `legend: {position: "bottom",},` into the chart options, but it's not worked. Is there any other way to do that?

```
<template>
  <Bar
    :chart-options="chartOptions"
    :chart-data="chartData"
    :chart-id="chartId"
    :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
    :plugins="plugins"
    :css-classes="cssClasses"
    :styles="styles"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs/legacy";

import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale
);

export default {
  name: "BarChart",
  components: {
    Bar,
  },
  props: {
    chartId: {
      type: String,
      default: "bar-chart",
    },
    datasetIdKey: {
      type: String,
      default: "label",
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400,
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 400,
    },
    cssClasses: {
      default: "",
      type: String,
    },
    styles: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
    plugins: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: [
          "January",
          "February",
          "March",
          "April",
          "May",
          "June",
          "July",
          "August",
          "September",
          "October",
          "November",
          "December",
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data One",
            backgroundColor: "#f87979",
            data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11],
          },
        ],
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          position: "bottom",
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a **plugins** object and move legend inside of it

```
chartOptions: {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: "bottom",
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for this for hours still didn't find a proper documentation until this great answer was found!

Answer (score 0):

My two cents if some people use vue-chartjs with a Typescript environment on some charts as Pie, put legend as a prop inside chartOptions.plugins will throw an linter type error:

**The types of 'plugins.legend.position' are incompatible between these types.ts(2322)**

So you just need to force it as const as below: (not the proper way but I didn't found any workaround to resolve it)

```
chartOptions: {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: "bottom" as const,
    }
  }
},
```